# Adding Numbers to Strings (Python)

Tags: python

```
print("Hi, my name is {0}, and I work at {1}.".format("blank", 36)
```

why is this ^ ok but this  isnt  => `" blank" + 36`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), the `.format` method does "Returns a copy of the string where each replacement field is replaced with the string value of the corresponding argument".

So the arguments you provide to `.format` get converted to their string representations before being inserted into your string.

You'd have to do it manually to achieve the same by concatentating using the `+` operator:

```
" blank" + str(36)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate an integer (`36`) to a string (`" blank"`).

You would need to **cast** the integer into a string : `" blank" + str(36)`, but even if you do that,

```
print("Hi, my name is {0}, and I work at {1}.".format(" blank" + str(36)))
```

would **not** work because the inclusion of both `{0}` and `{1}` means that **two** arguments are expected in `format()`.

So something that **would** work is:

```
print("Hi, my name is {0}, and I work at {1}.".format(" blank" + str(36), "second required argument"))
```